# MySQL does not Import .SQL Dump Properly

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a .sql file with 24k INSERT statements as:

```
INSERT INTO dump(id, title, content, datetime, section) VALUES ('', 'Title up to 200 characters', 'Detailed content with HTML tags', '04-10-2010, 11:48 AM', 1);
```

Once import is completed, i get a message that says

> Import has been successfully finished, 24664 queries executed.

When i browse the table, i find many titles and contents are totally empty or carry part of texts only i.e. few letters.

The only parts that gets inserted properly is: id, datetime and section.

title and content carry heavy contents. Many "content" might carry 250 char+. Title carries around 100 chars max.

On the other hand, i find copy/paste few pieces of INSERT and do it manually via SQL area. Everything gets inserted correctly. This method could take me very long time...

Any idea why i'm facing such a problem?

Comment: What created the dump?  Perhaps the dump itself contains errors.

Comment: I would find one specific row that hasn't imported properly, then copy it from the dump and see what happens when you paste it and add it manually.

Comment: Most rows hasn't imported properly...The dump was created manually using my own script. The INSERT statement is structured correctly.

Comment: Most likely you have some single quotes inside your title or content data. You should escape those characters.

Comment: If i take a single INSERT and insert it manually, i don't get any problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MYSQL to create your dumps try this command

```
mysqldump --extended-insert=FALSE --complete-insert=TRUE -p db_name
```

Comment: I had to use:
> SET NAMES UTF8 .........
> source dumpfile.sql ........ Assuming dumpfile.sql is of type UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Check the max_allowed_packet size and be sure that is not hurting your inserts.

Comment: I've run into this one several times... it's a good place to start